# How to limit the amount of simultaneously running jobs of a certain "type"?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to be able to limit the amount of jobs of a given "type" that run at the same time (maybe based on their label, e.g. no more than N jobs with label `mylabel` may run at the same time).

I have a long running computation that requires a license key to run.  I have N license keys and I would like to limit the amount of simultaneously running jobs to N. Here's how I imagine it working: I label the jobs with some special `tag`.  Then, I schedule N + K jobs, then at most N jobs may be in state "running" and K jobs should be in the queue and may only transition to "running" state when the total number of running jobs labeled `mytag` is less or equal to N.

[UPDATE]

- The jobs are independent of each other.
- The execution order is not important, although I would like them to be FIFO (time wise).
- The jobs are scheduled on user requests. That is, there is no fixed amount of work known in advance that needs to be processed, the requests to run a job with some set of parameters (configuration file) come sporadically in time.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what kind of computations you run? Are they independent of each other? Should there be some execution order? How do you start these jobs? And what Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @IvanM. The jobs are independent of each other.  The execution order is not important, although I would like them to be FIFO (time wise).  Not sure exactly what do you mean by "How do you start these jobs?", I try my best to give some details: they are scheduled by a service; all jobs are created form the same template, the container that a job runs does some number crunching simulations; the difference between the jobs is in the configuration file for the simulations.

Comment: @IvanM. Each running container uses a license key.  I have N license keys, so I don't want to run more than N containers, but I do want to be able to schedule as many jobs as I want to, say N+K and let the remaining K jobs sit till some of the initial N jobs are finished and then some of the K jobs can start.

Comment: @IvanM. The jobs are scheduled on user requests.  That is, there is no fixed amount of work known in advance that needs to be processed, the requests to run a job with some set of parameters (configuration file) come sporadically in time.

Comment: @IvanM. I had an idea that this might be done with a custom controller.  Raised a question here: https://github.com/nolar/kopf/discussions/891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in feature to do it using labels in k8s. But since your jobs are scheduled based on unpredictable user requests, you can achieve your goal like this:

- create a new namespace `kubectl create namespace quota-pod-ns`
- create a ResourceQuota

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: pod-max-number
  namespace: quota-pod-ns
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "5"
```

This  will limit max number of pods to 5 in the namespace quota-pod-ns.

- create k8s jobs in the quota-pod-ns namespace.

When you want to run the 6th job in that namespace, k8s will try to create the 6th pod and will fail to do that. But once one of the running pods is Completed, job-controller will create that new pod within a max limit.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!

Comment: Just tried it out with some dummy jobs.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can ‘parallelism’ attribuate of the job, but K8s won’t spin any jobs till the current active be less than parallel threshild